AsyncStorage from Supabase throws NativeModule: AsyncStorage is null
In my Expo react native App, I'm trying to use Supabase so I followed the documentation and added the supabase.ts file. I changed the extension to .js since all the project is js. I did supabase init supabase login I wonder if there's a step I missed or if it's something else but I'm getting the following error :
Error: [@RNC/AsyncStorage]: NativeModule: AsyncStorage is null.

here's what my code looks like :
import "react-native-url-polyfill/auto";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import { createClient } from "@supabase/supabase-js";

const supabaseUrl = process.env.SUPABASE_URL;
const supabaseAnonKey = process.env.SUPABASE_ANON_KEY;

export const supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl, supabaseAnonKey, {
  auth: {
    storage: AsyncStorage,
    autoRefreshToken: true,
    persistSession: true,
    detectSessionInUrl: false,
  },
});

When I remove the asyncStorage import and everything related to it, I don't get that error
